# Hosting Tiddlywiki on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, tiddlywiki

I have a gaming group and we share a number of documents via Google Drive. I'm now looking at putting together a Tiddlywiki (or some other stand-alone wiki-like package) to keep track of all of the information they're discovering.

Can I put an instance of Tiddlywiki on Google Drive and share the folder in such a way that a small number of people can read it? If so, how? Can I make it read-only except for me?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found a solution, I would suggest looking to a service like Dropbox for hosting the wiki. Google posted that they are [deprecating web hosting support in Google Drive](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html) come August. A good alternate would be Dropbox. I briefly skimmed [Dropbox's help section](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/4459). I would say you should be able to share your blog with just your buddies, giving them read and/or write access.